# HTML5 / CSS3 Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

The other night I had the iTunes Visualizer (new not classic) playing. I started to think and wonder if it is possible to create a similar style type effects for transitioning of `div` or other tags to create a flashy effect. Here is the catch, while I assume something of that sort can be done in Flash is it possible to do it *without* flash and use HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, etc. ?

I know some amazing effects can be created. After some searching I have not found anything but I ask here two questions:

1. Can something similar to the iTunes visualizer be done?
2. If possible, How?

(Note: While I would love to support all browsers I am looking for if it is possible even if not supported in all browsers.)

Comment: What does it look like? I don't have iTunes.

Comment: Me neither; this is one case where I'd appreciate a YouTube (or similar) link.

Comment: I have iTunes, but which exact effect do you mean?

Comment: Check out http://daneden.me/animate/ for css based animations. This is about what can be done in css. For everything else, canvas.

Comment: @GoranObradovic - Love the animate.css => Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can all be done (possibly better) sans Flash.

Take a look at [CSS3 transformations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/), [Raphael.JS](http://raphaeljs.com/), and [HTML5 Canvas](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice tutorial on creating visuals using HTML5:

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/make-a-particle-system-in-html5-canvas

Answer (score 1):

The iTunes visualiser is seriously flashy. It's a big pill to swallow, but you're best off looking at [WebGL](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl/). You may very much enjoy looking into [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/).